# Alta de registros en MySQL con NodeJS (Backend) que no entra en "Success" y se queda colgado. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, nodejs, express

***Expongo el código para ver si alguien puede ayudarme***

**Código HTML con el botón que hace la llamada a la función:**

```
<div  id="btn_crearcurs" class="btn_curs">
     <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="crearCursos()">Crear cursos i aules</a>
</div>
```

**Controlador de AngularJS que pasa los datos a NodeJS:**

```
$scope.crearCursos = function () {
     $scope.loader.loading = true;
     var lista = $scope.selected;
     if (lista.length <1)
     {
         alert("No ha seleccionat ningún curs.");
     }
     else
     {
         $scope.loader.loading = true;
         $http.post("/cursos/cursosC", {
             'seleccio' : $scope.selected,
             'ip' : $rootScope.mi_ip,
             'usu' : $rootScope.idUsu,
             'cif' : $rootScope.cifAssoc
         })
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.loader.loading = false;                    
             $state.go("private.adminsAssoccurs");
         })
         .error(function (error) {
             $scope.loader.loading = false;
             console.log(error);
         });                
         $state.go("private.adminsAssoccurs");
     }
};
```

**Código (ruta) en NodeJS que inserta los registros en la base de datos MySQL:**

```
app.post('/cursos/cursosC', function (req, res) {
    var seleccio = req.body.seleccio;
    var ip = req.body.ip;
    var usuari = req.body.usu;
    var cif = req.body.cif;
    var valores = preparaMatriz(seleccio, ip, usuari, cif);
    db.get().query("INSERT INTO cursoscentres (cifAssocCursAssoc, cursAssoc, descripcioCursAssoc, aulaCursAssoc, datacreacioCursAssoc, ipcreacioCursAssoc, usuaricreacioCursAssoc, altaCursAssoc) VALUES ?", [valores], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            var data = {"error": 1, "err": err};
            return data;
        } else {
            var data = {"error": 0};
            //console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Eso que dices de "se queda colgado" es muy vago. Qué has hecho para determinar la causa del error? tienes errores en la consola? has hecho algun log? Recuerda leer el [tour] y [ask] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio y como hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Cómo comenta el administrador, es un poco vaga tu pregunta, pero me atrevería a decir y por eso te respondo, que tu problema es, en la parte de node, no devuelves la petición, el post recibe 'req' y 'res' (además de 'next' cómo tercer parámetro si lo necesitases), tras realizar el insert deberías hacer algo cómo:

```
res.send(data);
```

esto hace que express termine la request que se ha hecho y devuelva la respuesta al front, lee un poco en la api de express sobre el objeto Response. Pero vamos, tiene pinta de que ese es tu problema.

Comment: En primer lugar pedir disculpas al administrador y a todos los que hayan podido leer esta pregunta si les ha parecido vaga, pero es la primera vez que pongo una pregunta y no conocía los mecanismos del "recorrido" ni el de "Cómo preguntar". 
En segundo lugar agradecer a Kalamarico su tiempo y su solución pues ese era el error, ya que yo tenía puesto "return data" y lo que debería de poner era "return send(data)".
Muy agradecido y hasta la próxima que será mejor.

Comment: Me alegro Carlos!, saludos!